# sorting two arrays fails on two digit numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to create a function that will take the two arrays below: (Data is filled in elsewhere)

```
var playerImport = []
playerImport[0] = "";
playerImport[1] = "";
playerImport[2] = "";
playerImport[3] = "";
playerImport[4] = "";

var scoreImport = []
scoreImport[0] = "";
scoreImport[1] = "";
scoreImport[2] = "";
scoreImport[3] = "";
scoreImport[4] = "";
```

and sort the two arrays together.

For example, scoreImport[0] is the lowest value and once sorted, should carry down playerImport[0] with it.

I currently have this as my function.

```
function sortHighscores(a, b)
var swapped;  
do {  
    swapped = false;  
    for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {  
        if (a[i] > a[i+1])   
        {  
            var temp = a[i];  
            a[i] = a[i+1];  
            a[i+1] = temp;  

            var temp = b[i];  
            b[i] = b[i+1];  
            b[i+1] = temp;  
            swapped = true;  
        }  
    }  
} while (swapped);
```

Although this works, if I try to sort the two arrays and one or more of the scoreImport's contain a two digit number while the rest contains one, it just places it straight to the bottom and fails to sort correctly. For example, if scoreImport[4] = 20 and the rest are single digit numbers, the value of twenty is sorted to scoreImport[0], also known as the lowest value.

How can I get this function to understand sorting single and two digit values? It seems to crumble when faced with this challenge.

Hopefully you get the jist of what I'm trying to explain.

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are sorting as strings i guess, so '20' is smaller than '3' !

Comment: can you put some example values in, rather than just empty strings? the issue is probably that they are strings, rather than numbers, so "9" is greater than "11". Either store them as numbers or `parseInt()` them each time

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting strings, thus the order will not match numerically.

You can ...

1. Pad the stored values with zero, i.e. "01", "20" would sort correctly.
2. Convert to numeric value at some point before sorting, use `parseInt(number, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your values are sorted as strings and as you probably know `"20" < "3"`. Cast the values to `Number`s before comparing them. Eg `+value` or `Number(value)` or `parseInt(value,10)`